# mongodb does not use index for time series data

Tags: mongodb, bigdata, pymongo

I am new to MongoDB and NoSQL and I am trying to run queries on a huge data set (around 50 million documents)

I am running the latest version of MongoDB using Docker on a Windows 10 host with 64 GB RAM.

I am using `pymongo` to import the data and run queries and I also have `Mongo Express` running as a docker container to view the imported data.

My statement to create my time-series collection is:

```
mydb.command('create', 'sensor_data', timeseries={
    'timeField': 'collection_time', 
    'metaField': 'sensor' 
})
```

Each document looks something like this:

```
{
    "sensor": { "id": 1, "location":"Somewhere"},
    "collection_time": datetime.strptime("2022/01/01 01:23:45 PM", '%Y/%m/%d %I:%M:%S %p'),
    ...
}
```

I have been able to use `Mongo Express` to verify that the data has been loaded into MongoDB correctly.

I then tried to run the following bit of code:

```
res = mycol.find({
    "collection_time": { 
        "$gte": datetime.strptime("2021/01/01 12:00:00 AM", '%Y/%m/%d %I:%M:%S %p'), 
        "$lte": datetime.strptime("2022/02/01 12:00:00 AM", '%Y/%m/%d %I:%M:%S %p') 
    }
})
```

But this query takes a very long time to run.

After running `res.explain()` , I can see that the operation is doing a `COLSCAN` and not using an index. I even tried manually creating an index on 'collection_time' but the query is still doing a COLSCAN.
What am I missing?

## Update 1

Thanks to R2D2's solution, I have got this working for `find()`, but I can't get it to work for `aggregate()`
Here is my code:

```
res = mycol.aggregate([
    { 
        "$match": {
            "collection_time": { 
                "$gte": datetime.strptime("2021/01/01 12:00:00 AM", '%Y/%m/%d %I:%M:%S %p'), 
                "$lte": datetime.strptime("2022/02/01 12:00:00 AM", '%Y/%m/%d %I:%M:%S %p') 
            }
        }
    },
    {"$group":
        { 
            "_id": {
                 "year" : { "$year" : "$collection_time" },        
                "month" : { "$month" : "$collection_time" },        
                "day" : { "$dayOfMonth" : "$collection_time" },
            }, 
            "count":{ "$sum": 1}
        }
    }
], {hint: "collection_time_1" })
```

This gives the error: `NameError: name 'hint' is not defined`

Putting `hint` in quotes gives the error: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_txn_read_preference'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default when you create Time Series collection it is effective for storing time series data , but there is no indexes created , you can create [secondary indexes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/timeseries/timeseries-secondary-index/) for Time Series collection to improve performance for queries and if query planner do not select some of the created indexes you can add hint() to the query with the index name ( you can get the indexes names with db.collection.getIndexes() )

For mongodb 3.6+ you can use hint also in aggregation framework as follow:

```
 db.collection.aggregate(pipeline, {hint: "index_name"})
```

Comment: Great! using ```.hint()``` made my query almost instant. But how do I use this with the ```aggregate()``` function?

Comment: you can add in the aggregation parameters section as {hint:"index_name"} , updated my answer with the details ...

Comment: This gives me the error ```name 'hint' is not defined```. I have updated the question with my aggregate function.

Comment: for python syntax seem slightly different: hint (optional): An index, in the same format as passed to create_index() (e.g. [('field', ASCENDING)]).

Comment: bad news , checking the pymongo code it seems hint is not supported by python aggregation ...

Comment: Hmm .. well, thanks for your help. Perhaps I'll try this again in nodeJS (javascript) or Java (hopefully, I don't encounter the same issue)